# scala play how to pass variables to page

Tags: scala, playframework

In Scala + Play, how to put a variable into response ?

In page

@lastName @firstName

In application controller:

```
   def index = Action {
    implicit request =>{
        request.setAttribute("lastName", "john"); // not work
        Ok(views.html.index("xxx"))
    }
```

}

if in java servlet , we can do this way:

```
request.setAttribute("name", "value");
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

how to do the same in Scala + Play ?

Comment: Rhys has the correct answer, but you should take some time to dig into the concept of the templating engine.  Templates are type-safe and compiled, which gives you compile-time feedback (+ edit-time feedback depending on your IDE).  See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Overview for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use view/page variables.

In your view:

```
@(myStringVar: String)
<b>Hello @myStringVar</b>
```

Your controller:

```
def index = Action {
    implicit request => {
        Ok(views.html.index(myStringVar = "Ooo!"))
    }
}
```

Ref: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Overview